# Is it possible to append string to many matching rows in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

For an example, i have following table:

| Id | Name | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FirstCar | White |
| 2 | SecondCar | Yellow |
| 3 | ThirdCar | Red |
| 4 | FourthCar | White |
| 5 | FifthCar | Green |
| 6 | SixthCar | Blue |

What i need to achieve: append string "_123" to field "Name" for all rows where "Name" is "SecondCar", "FourthCar" or "SixthCar" resulting following:

| Id | Name | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FirstCar | White |
| 2 | SecondCar_123 | Yellow |
| 3 | ThirdCar | Red |
| 4 | FourthCar_123 | White |
| 5 | FifthCar | Green |
| 6 | SixthCar_123 | Blue |

How can i do this?

Comment: It would be great to have the DDL and DML statements for the same. Can you make an [SQLFiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/) at least? It will be easier to debug. Thanks.

Comment: Basically just ...CONCAT(name, '_123')...the question is if this should be a query or an update and how exactly the where clause should be (e.g. if checking using = or using like '%...%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), which will apply `_123` at our matching `where name in ('SecondCar','FourthCar','SixthCar')` condition .

```
UPDATE test set name = CONCAT(name,'_123') 
WHERE name IN ('SecondCar','FourthCar','SixthCar');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd790f9f30fecdb2f3dc22cb2d8ca0a5

**Note. This will update existing data**

Comment: What should be the purpose of this join instead of just doing this?: UPDATE test set name = CONCAT(name,'_123') 
WHERE name IN ('SecondCar','FourthCar','SixthCar');

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straightforward by using a [CASE WHEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) statement together with a [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_concat.asp) function:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN name IN ("SecondCar", "FourthCar", "SixthCar")
      THEN CONCAT(name, "_123")
    ELSE name
  END AS name,
  color
FROM your_table;
```